# Convert pay off matrix to LPs

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

Let's say I have this Matrix which represents the payoff for zero-sum game and I want to convert it to linear programs

[Pay off matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vc4y6.png)

Using the minimax theorem for zero-sum theory. I came up with these two LPs

```
Row player: 

    Maximize z

    Subject to:     -x1 –x2 –x3 – z >= 0
                    x1 – 2x2 – x3 – z >= 0
                    x1 – x2 + x3 – z >= 0
                    2x2 + x3 >= 0
                    x1 + x2 + x3 = 1
```

Column player:

```
Minimize w
Subject to:     -x1 + x2 + x3 -w <= 0
                -x1 – 2x2 – x3 + 2x4 -w <= 0
                -x1 – x2 + x3 + x4 -w <= 0
                x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 = 1
                x1,x2,x3,x4  >= 0
```

Can someone help me verify if my solutions are correct. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's better to align them first.

The dual of

```
Maximize z

Subject to:    -x1 –  x2 – x3 – z >= 0
                x1 – 2x2 – x3 – z >= 0
                x1 –  x2 + x3 – z >= 0
                     2x2 + x3     >= 0
                x1 +  x2 + x3      = 1
```

should be

```
Minimize w
Subject to:     -x1 +  x2 + x3       + w = 0
                -x1 – 2x2 – x3 + 2x4 + w = 0
                -x1 –  x2 + x3 +  x4 + w = 0
                -x1 -  x2 - x3           = 1
                x1,x2,x3,x4 <= 0, w free
```

The $\ge$ and $=$ signs in the primal problem corresponds to dual variables $x_i \le 0$ and $w$ free.  The primal variables $x_i,z$ free corresponds to the equalities in the dual.